# Duda con decorador [Route(" ")]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data-atributos

Tengo el siguiente `controller`

```
[Route("micontrolador")]
public class MiController : Controller
{
    [Route("micontrolador/miaccion")]
    public ActionResult Index() => View();
}
```

*path micontrolador/miaccion*

¿Es necesario indicar en el controlador la ruta de este o solo basta con agregarle el `[Route]` a los métodos de los controladores?

Para que quede asi

```
public class MiController : Controller
{
    [Route("micontrolador/miaccion")]
    public ActionResult Index() => View();
}
```

*path micontrolador/miaccion*

Comment: El atributo`Route` a nivel de controlador específica una ruta base para todas las acciones del mismo. Tu acción bien podría quedar así `[Route("miaccion")]`. Pero si específicas así el valor del atributo `[Route("/miaccion")]`  el acceso al recurso sería un`GET /miaccion` en vez de `GET /micontrolador/miaccion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a este [artículo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), es correcto definir las rutas directamente en el método, sin tener que repetirlas en el controlador.

Tu segunda opción entonces debería funcionar:

```
public class MiController : Controller
{
    [Route("micontrolador/miaccion")]
    public ActionResult Index() => View();
}
```

Comment: Gracias, leeré ese articulo.